# Regarding inverse of the Poisson integral operator

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory, harmonic-analysis

Let $\mathbb{T}, \mathbb{D}$ be the unit circle and unit disc respectively in the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$. For $f\in L^\infty(\mathbb{T})$, the Poisson Integral map $P:L^\infty(\mathbb{T})\longrightarrow h^\infty(\mathbb{D})(f\in L^\infty(\mathbb{D})$  which are harmonic) is defined as
$$P(f)(re^{i\theta})=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{\frac{1-r^2}{1+r^2-2cos(\theta-t)}}f(e^{it})dt\;\;\;\;\;(re^{i\theta})\in \mathbb{D}.$$ It is known that this map is onto also.

I wanted to know if $$f(0)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(P^{-1}\circ f)(e^{it})dt\;\;\;\;\;f\in h^\infty(\mathbb{D}) $$ is true?

Comment: dominated convergent theorem should work as the result is true for $f_r(e^{it})=f(re^{it})$, $f_r \to P^{-1} \circ f, r \to 1$ ae and $||f_r|| \le ||P^{-1} \circ f||\ < \infty$